# adding value again and again in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

In my JavaScript I have three `Links`. The `second link` is open depends upon the `first link id` selected. Everything works fine. But After selecting the `second link`, if i want to change the `first link`, the `second link` is still opens for the old `id`.If I want to change the `first link`, all the `fields` should change and opens as per the `first link.`

```
 var generic_lookup_Enr_Rds_Section2009_selected = function(id, to_s) {
      var question_link = $('#question_picker').attr('href');
      question_link = question_link.replace(/\?+$/, '');
      question_link = question_link + '?columns[enr_rds_section_id]=' + id;
      $('#question_picker').attr('href', question_link);
      $("#modal_popup").dialog("destroy");

  };

  var generic_lookup_Enr_Rds_Question2009_selected = function(id, to_s) {
      var answer_link = $('#answer_picker').attr('href');
      answer_link = answer_link.replace(/\?+$/, '');
      answer_link = answer_link + '?columns[enr_rds_question_id]=' + id;
      $('#answer_picker').attr('href', answer_link);
      $("#modal_popup").dialog("destroy");
  };
```

### html

```
<div class="question">
      <%= f.label :Section %>
      <%= link_to pro_generic_lookup_data_path("Enr::Rds::Section2009", format: :js), data: {remote: true} do %>
        <%= image_tag("Search-icon.gif", border: 0, :alt => "Look up Sections", title: 'Lookup Sections') %>
      <% end %>
 </div>

  <div class="question">
      <%= f.label :Question %>
      <%= link_to pro_generic_lookup_data_path("Enr::Rds::Question2009", format: :js), data: {remote: true}, id: "question_picker" do %>
        <%= image_tag("Search-icon.gif", border: 0, :alt => "Look up Questions", title: 'Lookup Questions', :class => "image_section_search") %>
      <% end %>
 </div>
```

Comment: Where's the corresponding HTML?  And, what exactly is the question?

Comment: Can you condense your code to the minimum where you seem to face the problem?

Comment: Hi I edited and condensed. My problem is field question is open depends upon the section selected. With this code its working fine. But after I select the section and question, if i want to change the section again, the question got the previous id of section and opens only for that id. not for the new.

Comment: Can you not add an EventListener to the first `<select>` and have the contents of the second one reload based on the selection?

Comment: I am very new to Javascript and Ruby on Rails. So struggling.

Comment: I summarized the question. If, its not clear, please send a message. i will explain in detail

Comment: I don't see any markup for "input" fields (maybe i'm just missing something here).  If you are indeed using input field elements, you should look at using the "change" method to trigger input value re-initialization in all fields.

Comment: Actually there is no input field. its a dialog box will open the generic lookup data.

Comment: so where is the input?  your original question states "I have three input fields"

Comment: Hi Sorry. If i not clearly define the question. So sorry for that. I have three links to open.

Comment: ok that's not a problem.  then bind an event handler to ".click()" or ".on('click',eventHandler)" to re-initialize your id's or whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks, I dont know how to re-initialize. I am very new to Javascript. Any example that would be more appreciated. Thanks

Comment: ok, here's a quick example on how to handle the click event within a group of divs.  this is just a simple pattern, with no production-ready qualities, but it should get you started...http://jsfiddle.net/dEGkY/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by Javascript using cascading dropdown function by example. Thanks guys.